# Proof that you can always find two parallel planes for skew lines.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I read that given two skew lines, you can always construct two parallel planes that pass through each skew line respectively.
This is my "attempt" at a proof:
Suppose you have two lines, l1 and l2. Taking the cross product of a vector parallel to l1 lets call it v1 and a vector parallel to l2 lets call it v2 you get a vector n that is perpendicular to both of vectors. My intuition says that the planes formed by v1 and n is parallel to the plane formed by v2 and n. Can someone explain why my intuition is correct or incorrect mathematically.

If there is an intuitive way to see that you can always find two parallel planes for skew lines I would also be interested in that.

Comment: "I read that you can always construct two parallel planes for two skew lines." It isn't clear to me what this means. Do you mean, "Given two skew lines, you can always construct two parallel planes that pass through each skew line respectively", or something like that?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. I will edit it to make it more clear.

Comment: Your intuition is incorrect. Those planes you describe can definitely intersect each other. What you *should* do is form a plane that is *perpendicular* to $n$ such that $l_1$ lies on the plane and  form a second plane that is *perpendicular* to $n$ such that $l_2$ lies on the plane. This will work because two any two planes perpendicular to a (normal) line will be parallel.

Answer (score 1):

The rough idea is:

Let the two skew lines $L_1$ and $L_2$ have direction vectors $\vec{v_{1}}$ and $\vec{v_{2}}$ respectively.

Consider a plane defined by normal vectors $\vec{v_{1}}$ and $\vec{v_{2}}$. 
Equation looks like: $\vec{x} = t\cdot\vec{v_{1}} + s\cdot\vec{v_{2}} + \vec{u}$, where $\vec{u}$ is some vector that the plane contains.

It's clear now that we can make a plane that contains $L_1$ and a plane that contains $L_2$, by changing the value of $\:\vec{u}\:$. These planes would also be parallel as they have the same direction vectors, and this is what we wanted.